# How to write fuzzing tests against the Linux KVM?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, virtualization, fuzzing

It should be the case that the Linux kernel, when it is a host kernel, should not be adversely affected by what a guest kernel executes inside a virtual machine.

I'd like to test that property by fuzzing the interface from the guest kernel to the host kernel. It seems clear to me that the test needs to run inside the guest kernel (say, in a kernel module), generate arbitrary code, and then execute that code. The test fails if the host kernel crashes (or does something "interesting").

So, my questions are:

- Do you know of any tests that already accomplish this?
- Are there instructions that are *expected* to crash the host kernel that I need to avoid?
- What is the best way to generate garbage inside the Linux kernel?
- Once I've generated the garbage, how do I execute it?

For the time being, I'd like to just focus on the general fuzzing approach. Later on after I get this test working, I'll change it to surgically fuzz different virtualized instructions and drivers in the kernel.

**Update:** After thinking about it further, fuzzing with complete garbage isn't going to work since I'll be crashing my guest machine way more often than I expect to be crashing my host. So, I think I need to approach this surgically from the start. Any advice?

Comment: A bit ambitious,  perhaps you should cut your teeth by hacking an easier project.

Answer (score 3):

To a large extent finding serous 0-days is about writing imaginative tests.   When you are building a test a system you need to identify its attack surface.   In web applications this is easy,  GET/POST requests.   For something like a VM,  its more complex.  The actual hardware provided to you,  is an illusion created by the KVM.  At some point this data interaction with this device will be processed by the host.

Other important resource is looking for vulnerabilities that have already been found in your target.  Often times programmers make very similar mistakes,  and similar bugs are very common.  [These CVE's: CVE-2010-0297 CVE-2010-0298 CVE-2010-0306 CVE-2010-0309](http://freshmeat.net/articles/red-hat-updated-kvm-packages-fix-multiple-security-issues),  are a good examples of vulnerabilities LInux's KVM.  Two hardware devices that stick out are the CPU and USB,  which where both compromised.

A very powerful fuzzing platform is [Peach](http://peachfuzzer.com/).  Many tests can be created using XML alone, although if you know python you can extend peach to do anything.

Comment: Is 'imaginative' similar to 'ambitious'? :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to those CVEs; I'm not yet familiar with out the virtualized devices work, so I'll use those as a starting point.

Comment: I wonder how I would go about interfacing Peach (python) with a kernel module, though? Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @Jeremy Powell,  in linux everything is a file.   Devices can be found in /dev/.  A cheap way of fuzzing could be for peach to open one of these files and start writing to the device.  Although if you learn how device drivers are written you will be more successful.

Answer (score 0):

While fuzzing device drivers is often productive, most of those are not emulated by KVM, but by a userspace component. USB drivers, as the previous answer gave as an example, are emulated entirely by QEMU. While funding a vulnerability in the emulated EHCI driver would be fantastic, it would not be a KVM vulnerability, and it would not allow you to develop a kernel exploit. There are a few drivers which are emulated in KVM, such as certain PIC timers (e.g. i8254 and i8259), but the majority are kept in userspace.

Another thing which KVM emulates are certain instructions. You could fuzz KVM by fuzzing these specific instructions. Read the KVM source to see which are the most complex, and how to trigger the most complex or sensitive behavior. On older CPU architectures where the CPU cannot provide real mode execution to the guest (unrestricted_guest=1), even more instructions are emulated.

Especially when it comes to exploiting instruction emulation, race conditions can often be involved.